# Merging two branches where the directory structure has changed

Tags: git

I have a codebase where the directory structure changed (framework upgrade). I created a `upgrade` branch off `master`.

While making and testing these updates, more changes went into the `master` branch.

Now I need to merge the changes on the `master` branch into `upgrade` and make `upgrade` the *default* (`master`) branch.

I ran:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout upgrade
git pull upstream upgrade
git merge upstream/master
```

For the most part, this surprisingly worked. However, because of the directory change, several files show as *deleted by us* which had modifications in `master`.

Is there a way, short of copying changes by hand, git can pull over the modifications before marking these files for delete?

Comment: Just an idea: turn [rerere](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/08/rerere.html) on, then merge an older version of master (before the move) into the upgrade branch, then merge the result into master.

Comment: Theoretically git is supposed to have detected the rename and applied the changes in the appropriate place during the merge...did it not do that ? Was it a simple rename, or was it a rename+modifications?

Comment: Did you use `git mv` or did you just use rename/move the files?

Comment: @Andrew C, that may have been the problem. I will check the logs. If so, is there no way?

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of what happened I could only make wild guesses.  A simple rename is easy to identify because the SHA of the blob in the tree object will be the same.  Git really should be doing the correct thing in those instances.  How well `git merge` handles the rename+change case can depend on a few factors, possibly including the settings for merge.renameLimit and diff.renameLimit if they are set.

Comment: Yes, looking back at the history, it appears these came across as new files in the `upgrade` branch (i.e. not a `git mv`). I imagine that's my problem with these specific files and not others. Is there any hope for these specific files that were *added*.

Comment: You can abort and retry with different rename settings and may get some help there, otherwise hand merges sound inevitable